# visual studio 2013 - references not being found after get from TFS

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, tfs

I'm trying to set up my dev environment from work on my home computer. I connected through the vpn to TFS and got latest, but the project won't build because references aren't being found. It appears that the references not found all have a path of...

```
<HintPath> \\tfsdrops\TFSBuilds\ThirdPartyLibraries\... </HintPath>
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on/how to fix?
I have VS2013 and targeting .net 4.5.1...

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access the \tfsdrop share in windows explorer? Try and connect to the share before you open the solution and as long as you can then it should work.

Personally I prefer to keep libs either in a libs folder that is checked out with the solution or using nuget packages - either of those stops this sort of issue.

Comment: NuGet packages are the only real solution for this.

Comment: I've used lib folders fine, I would consider both :)

Comment: As storing binaries inside of Source Control is considered a bad practice, where are you keeping them if not in Nuget?